# How can I merge a vendor's css file into my gulp scss task?

Tags: css, sass, gulp

This is my current `sass` task:

```
var config = {
    sassPath: './src/scss',
    bowerDir: './bower_components',
    nodeDir: './node_modules'
}

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src(config.sassPath + '/application.scss')
        .pipe(
            sass({
                outputStyle: 'compressed',
                includePaths: [
                    './src/scss',
                    config.bowerDir + '/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets',
                    config.bowerDir + '/font-awesome/scss'
                ]
            })
            .on("error", notify.onError(function(error){
                return "Error: " + error.message;
            }))
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css'));
});
```

I am now needing to also copy in a css file into my final css file.

It is located at `config.nodeDir + "/react-select/dist/default.css"`.

Do I need to use an external merge task to accomplish this? Do I need to have a separate `css` task - and if so, would it append to the `application.css` that exists or would it replace the css filled from the `sass` task? I thought this would be relatively simple but I'm having troubles.

Comment: Do you have the means to change the css file to _default.scss?  If so you can import _default.scss into your main scss file.

Comment: This is what I've done for now. It just seems like I'm cheating a little bit - for example, if I wanted to upgrade the package, I would have to copy the new .css file over again.

Comment: Yep, thats the down side.  If you were bringing in an external css file or want to eliminate the manual file renaming process then gulp would be the way to go.